# How to assign an output of class list to a variable in R?

Tags: r, list

My data looks like

```
   Name  Pd1 Pd2 Pd3 Pd4  
    A     2   6   8   9
    B     6   3   7   1
```

I want to collect the name of columns that has values from highest to lowest.
I wish to see my data like

```
   Name        pdts
    A   c(pd4,pd3,pd2,pd1)
    B   c(Pd3,Pd1,Pd2,Pd4)
```

Kindly help me to do this in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `data.table` with `apply` function with `sort.list` to do this:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df <- df[, list(list((colnames(.SD)[c(t(apply(.SD, 1, function(x) sort.list(x, decreasing = T))))]))) ,Name]

print(df)

   Name              V1
1:    A Pd4,Pd3,Pd2,Pd1
2:    B Pd3,Pd1,Pd2,Pd4
```

**Explanation:**

1.`apply(.SD, 1, function(x) sort.list(x, decreasing = T)` - Gives the indexes of columns row wise.

2.`t` - We transpose the result to get a row wise vector.

3.`[c(t(apply(.SD, 1, function(x) sort.list(x, decreasing = T))))]` - this complete function return the sorted index of columns wise, that's the thing we need to solve this problem.

4.`colnames(.SD)` - .SD is a special symbol used in data.table. It basically refers to the grouped data and here we get the column names.

5.Finally, we sort the column names based on the indexes we got in step 3.

6.And, we group by `Name` column to get the solution for each Name.

7.You might find this overwhelming, so to understand, do it step by step and see how the solution evolves.